# Launch Testflight app for beta feedback

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm in the process of converting an app to using the new TestFlight system supplied by Apple. Previously the app would have a feedback dialog which would use the `submitFeedback` API. Now Apple's TestFlight app has a feedback mechanism, but it requires users to open that app manually. I think this is not as easy as it should be.

I'm currently considering soliciting feedback via email (MFMailComposeViewController), but is there a way to open Testflight from my app, such as using `UIApplication openURL:`?

Comment: I flagged as a duplicate but the question has yet to be answered..

Comment: Given some partial info (the url scheme) on the other question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @rdurand. I didn't find that question before posting myself!